# Why is there a "0 CLEARED by call to connect method" warning in DBI_TRACE?

Tags: perl, dbi, suppress-warnings

I'm wondering why a *warn* appears when using `DBI_TRACE=1` upon connecting to any DB. Bonus points to a way to write *clean* code that doesn't exhibit it.

I'm speaking about the `!! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method` that seems harmless,
since the code does work as intended. Note that it doesn't appear without setting the DBI trace mode.

Sample Perl code (using SQLite):

```
use warnings;
use DBI;
DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.sqlite","","") or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Sample output :

```
    DBI 1.612-ithread default trace level set to 0x0/1 (pid 12814 pi 1ddd010) at DBI.pm line 275 via test.pl line 2
    -> DBI->connect(dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.sqlite, , ****)
    -> DBI->install_driver(SQLite) for linux perl=5.010001 pid=12814 ruid=1000 euid=1000
       install_driver: DBD::SQLite version 1.29 loaded from /usr/lib/perl5/DBD/SQLite.pm
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x204da38)
    !! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method
    <- connect('dbname=test.sqlite', '', ...)= DBI::db=HASH(0x204e278) at DBI.pm line 662
    <- STORE('PrintError', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 714
    <- STORE('AutoCommit', 1)= 1 at DBI.pm line 714
    <- STORE('PrintWarn', 0)= 1 at DBI.pm line 717
    <- FETCH('PrintWarn')= '' at DBI.pm line 717
    <- STORE('Warn', 0)= 1 at DBI.pm line 717
    <- FETCH('Warn')= '' at DBI.pm line 717
    <- STORE('Username', '')= 1 at DBI.pm line 717
    <> FETCH('Username')= '' ('Username' from cache) at DBI.pm line 717
    <- connected('dbi:SQLite:dbname=test.sqlite', '', ...)= undef at DBI.pm line 723
    <- connect= DBI::db=HASH(0x204e278)
    <- STORE('dbi_connect_closure', CODE(0x204da08))= 1 at DBI.pm line 732
    <- DESTROY(DBI::db=HASH(204e1d0))= undef
    <- disconnect_all= '' at DBI.pm line 740
!   <- DESTROY(DBI::dr=HASH(204da38))= undef during global destruction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from the following XS code included with DBI:

```
if (!keep_error && meth_type != methtype_set_err) {
    SV *err_sv;
    if (trace_level && SvOK(err_sv=DBIc_ERR(imp_xxh))) {
        PerlIO *logfp = DBILOGFP;
        PerlIO_printf(logfp, "    !! %s: %s CLEARED by call to %s method\n",
            SvTRUE(err_sv) ? "ERROR" : strlen(SvPV_nolen(err_sv)) ? "warn" : "info",
            neatsvpv(DBIc_ERR(imp_xxh),0), meth_name);
    }
    DBIh_CLEAR_ERROR(imp_xxh);
} 
else {      /* we check for change in ErrCount during call */
    ErrCount = DBIc_ErrCount(imp_xxh);
}
```

It is simply a print to the trace file of the string "warn", it is not an issued warning. I think it is happening in your case because the connect method is SQLite is setting DBI's err to '0' so it is false but not zero length.

However, I see it happens with multiple DBDs (including DBD::ODBC).

Comment: Interesting. So the fix would be in DBD::SQLite ?

Comment: I thought so at first but it seems multiple DBDs output that trace string - including DBD::ODBC which I maintain and I'm not aware of doing anything special.

Comment: I think it's a bug in the drivers.

Comment: At this point I don't think it is a bug in the drivers as I've traced it through DBD::ODBC and D::O never sets "0", only "". However, I cannot as yet track it down in DBI. It is "" when DBIh_SET_ERR_CHAR is called but "0" when that message is output.

Comment: even with perl -MDBI -le 'my $h = DBI->connect("dbi:Sponge:")'  something sets err to "0"

Comment: I think it is down to my ($h_state_store, $h_err_store, $h_errstr_store) = (undef, 0, ''); in _new_drh in DBI.

Comment: It is fixed in the DBI git repository now - see "Fixed err for new drh to be undef not to 0" at https://github.com/perl5-dbi/dbi/blob/master/Changes