# Why is DBI connect not responding or throwing an error?

Tags: oracle, perl, proxy, dbi

I am trying to test an Oracle database access over a proxy with the following (working) script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

print "Start ->\n";
my $driver = "Proxy";
my $host = "*******";
my $port = "2001";
my $database = "********";
my $driver2 = "Oracle";
my $userid = "******";
my $password = "*****";

my $dsn = "dbi:$driver:hostname=$host;port=$port;dsn=dbi:$driver2:$database";

print "Connect to database ->\n";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password) or die $DBI::errstr;

print "Read data ->\n";  
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL");       
$sth->execute() or die $DBI::errstr;

print "Number of rows found :". $sth->rows;  
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   my ($sysdate) = @row;
   print "   System Time = $sysdate\n";
}
$sth->finish();

print "Disconnect ->\n"; 
$dbh = $dbh->disconnect  or warn $dbh->errstr;
```

When I run this the only output is

```
Start ->
Connect to database ->
[blank line]
```

and then nothing else happens (waited for more than a minute) and I have to break the process with CTRL+C.

I did verify that the script in general is working by connecting to another host/proxy. So I assume there must be something special going on with the proxy I am currently testing.

My question is: What could be the reason for the script to just halt without providing any error, and is there any way to get more information about the connection attempt (should the access attempt already be logged on the target system at this point) ?

***EDIT***

As suggested by the comment I ran the script via "DBI_TRACE=15 perl scriptname.pl" and got the following output:

```
Connect to database ->
    -> DBI->connect(dbi:Proxy:hostname=*****;port=2001;dsn=dbi:Oracle:******, *****, ****)
    -> DBI->install_driver(Proxy) for linux perl=5.008005 pid=31261 ruid=27003 euid=27003
       install_driver: DBD::Proxy version 0.2004 loaded from /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBD/Proxy.pm
    New DBI::dr (for DBD::Proxy::dr, parent=, id=)
    dbih_setup_handle(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88)=>DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), DBD::Proxy::dr, 0, Null!)
    dbih_make_com(Null!, 0, DBD::Proxy::dr, 112, 0) thr#0
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), Err, Null!) SCALAR(0x9fdf9d0) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), State, Null!) SCALAR(0x9fdf9b8) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), Errstr, Null!) SCALAR(0x9fdf9e8) (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), TraceLevel, Null!) 0 (already defined)
    dbih_setup_attrib(DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc), FetchHashKeyName, Null!) 'NAME' (already defined)
    >> STORE       DISPATCH (DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88) rc1/1 @3 g0 ima41c pid#31261) at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBD/Proxy.pm line 76
    -> STORE in DBD::_::common for DBD::Proxy::dr (DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88)~0x9f96edc 'CompatMode' 1)
    STORE DBI::dr=HASH(0x9f96edc) 'CompatMode' => 1
       warn: 0 '' (err#0)
    <- STORE= 1 at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBD/Proxy.pm line 76
    <- install_driver= DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88)
    >> connect     DISPATCH (DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88) rc2/3 @5 g0 ima1 pid#31261) at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBI.pm line 625
    !! warn: 0 CLEARED by call to connect method
    -> connect for DBD::Proxy::dr (DBI::dr=HASH(0x9fdcf88)~0x9f96edc 'hostname=****;port=2001;dsn=dbi:Oracle:*****' '*****' **** HASH(0x9f0f834))
```

Will try to find out what that actually means. :)

***EDIT2***

According to [Why is there a "0 CLEARED by call to connect method" warning in DBI_TRACE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983601/why-is-there-a-0-cleared-by-call-to-connect-method-warning-in-dbi-trace) the "warn" lines aren't the culprit. So I am as wise as before the trace ?

***EDIT3***

Quite the adventure. I did let the script idle in the background and like after 4 minutes it actually stopped and delivered more tracing godness:

```
 >> set_err     DISPATCH (DBI::dr=HASH(0x8d1fedc) rc1/3 @4 g0 ima11 pid#32187) at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBD/Proxy.pm line 89
1   -> set_err in DBD::_::common for DBD::Proxy::dr (DBI::dr=HASH(0x8d1fedc)~INNER 1 'Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Cannot connect: Connection timed out at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/RPC/PlClient.pm line 70. at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/Net/Daemon/Log.pm line 136.
' '     ')
    !! ERROR: 1 'Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Cannot connect: Connection timed out at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/RPC/PlClient.pm line 70. at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/Net/Daemon/Log.pm line 136.
' (err#1)
1   <- set_err= undef at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBD/Proxy.pm line 89
    !! ERROR: 1 'Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Cannot connect: Connection timed out at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/RPC/PlClient.pm line 70. at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/Net/Daemon/Log.pm line 136.
' (err#1)
    <- connect= undef at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/i686-linux/DBI.pm line 625
    -> $DBI::errstr (&) FETCH from lasth=HASH
    >> DBD::Proxy::dr::errstr
    <- $DBI::errstr= 'Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Cannot connect: Connection timed out at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/RPC/PlClient.pm line 70. at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/Net/Daemon/Log.pm line 136.
'
       DBI connect('hostname=*****;port=2001;dsn=dbi:Oracle:****','*****',...) failed: Cannot log in to DBI::ProxyServer: Cannot connect: Connection timed out at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/RPC/PlClient.pm line 70. at /opt/perl585/lib/site_perl/5.8.5/Net/Daemon/Log.pm line 136.
[... more of the same and the final DESTROY ...]
```

So the target proxy/host seems to be just offline or behind a firewall (would I get the same response in the latter case) ?

Comment: Enable [tracing](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.631/DBI.pm#TRACING) within DBI

Comment: Not sure if this is your issue but noticed the following in the [DBI docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Signal-Handling-and-Canceling-Operations): *With Oracle for instance (DBD::Oracle), if the system which hosts the database is down the DBI->connect() call will hang for several minutes before returning an error.*

Comment: You seem to have answered both of your questions ("What could be the reason for the script to just halt without providing any error, and is there any way to get more information about the connection attempt?"). You should write your findings as an answer.

Comment: Also, the section of the docs I linked to in my first comment describes how to set a timeout, which you could use to prevent your script from hanging for too long.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, is there any way to differentiate an offline server, being blocked by a firewall or being blocked by the server (via IP masking or something like that), in this scenario ?